# How to enable CPU Load in JProfiler?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jvm, jprofiler, cpu-load

[image]Hi,

I am trying to profile a J2EE application with JProfiler.

I am not able to chek the CPU Load under Telemetries tab of JProfiler. Below is the screenshot. Can someone please help.

I even looked at [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/tutorials/profilingjavaapplicationsusingrad/) and [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1110_sharath/1110_sharath.html).

The first link is very specific about enabling Profiling in RSA. But later talks about enabling profiling to JVM.

Can some one confirm about my understanding of second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you profile an IBM VM where this information is not available.

Comment: How do i enable that?

Comment: Also can you please check if this link will suffice : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1110_sharath/1110_sharath.html

Comment: It cannot be enabled for an IBM VM, you have to use a hot spot VM (Oracle) for that.

Comment: So do I have to connect that with IBM VM ? How can I achieve that?

Comment: No, instead of an IBM VM, you have to use an Oracle VM for profiling.